# Use terser webpack plugin instead of uglify when copying sources via plugin

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification, webpack-4, uglifyjs, terser

I have following packages in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJS = require("uglify-es");
```

And this is a part of my config that uses these packages:

```
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: {
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js",
        to: "./js/polyfills/whatwg-fetch.js",
        transform: content => UglifyJS.minify(content.toString()).code,
      },
    ]),
  }
```

Thus I minimize my common bundles with `terser` and provide minification via `uglify` for sources that are being copied by `copy-webpack` plugin. I want to get rid of `uglify` and replace it with `terser` since they both are being used for minification. Is it possible? Can `terser` plugin be used outside the `optimization` config section? Or maybe I can in some way tell him to minimize also my manually copied sources?

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be simple. Since `terser-webpack-plugin` includes `terser`, it can be used standalone.

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const Terser = require("terser");
```

And no need to add `terser` to the dependency list! Then we can use it explicitly whenever we want:

```
  plugins: {
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js",
        to: "./js/polyfills/whatwg-fetch.js",
        transform: content => Terser.minify(content.toString()).code,
      },
    ]),
  }
```